# Unicode-like encoding for filenames using Windows10-NFS-client and Linux-NFS-server

Tags: windows, nfs, encoding

**Problem**

The NFS-Client of *Windows10 Pro* mount an NFS-share with `lang=ansi` by default. This causing problems using filenames with umlauts or asian characters (e.g. Kanji, Hiragana, Katakana, etc).

**Details about my setup**

Server is *Debian GNU/Linux 10.6 (buster)*.
Support NFS-Version by that server from 3 to 4.2 (2 is disabled):

```
$ sudo cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions
-2 +3 +4 +4.1 +4.2
```

The client is `Windows10-Pro build 19041`. It is unknown for me which NFS-protocol version is used by the client. This are the options for the mount point.

```
UID=-2, GID=-2
rsize=131072, wsize=131072
mount=soft, timeout=0.8
retry=1, locking=yes
fileaccess=755, lang=ANSI
casesensitive=no
s=sys
```

I know there are [other options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mount) for `lang=`.

```
euc-jp: Japanese
euc-tw: Chinese
euc-kr: Korean
shift-jis: Japanese
Big5: Chinese
Ksc5601: Korean
Gb2312-80: Simplified Chinese
Ansi: ANSI-encoded
```

But none of them looks usefull for me.

Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, windows supports NFSv3, which is uses XDR **string** as a type for the file names., which is limited to ASCII:

NFSv3 spec
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#section-2.5

> typedef string filename3<>;

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1014#section-3.10

> The standard defines a string of n (numbered 0 through n-1) ASCII
> bytes to be the number n encoded as an unsigned integer (as described
> above), and followed by the n bytes of the string.

IOW, NFS v3 doesn't supports unicode

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#section-3.2